# Rails 3 domain-relative url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In **Rails 2**, you could add a leading slash to the :controller param to get a domain-relative url. Such as this:

```
# anywhere in the app, Rails 2
>> url_for(:controller => '/posts', :action => 'index')
=> "/posts"
```

However, in **Rails 3**, this appears to not work *if* you are in a deeply nested controller. For instance, if I'm in Home::Foo, it works. If I'm in Home::Foo::Bar, it doesn't work:

```
# in Home, works
>> url_for(:controller => '/posts', :action => 'index')
=> "/posts"

# in Home::Foo, works
>> url_for(:controller => '/posts', :action => 'index')
=> "/posts"

# in Home::Foo::Bar, does not work
>> url_for(:controller => '/posts', :action => 'index')
=> "home//posts"
```

**Question is:** what is the proper Rails 3 way of getting a domain-relative link using url_for()?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use the restful path of posts?

routes.rb

```
map.resources :posts
```

anyview.html.erb

```
posts_path
```

That should generate '/posts' wherever you are at.

Comment: Problem with this is that then you have to modify the routes.rb for every controller... it's not a bad solution, but it kind of defeats the purpose of `:controller=>`, doesn't it?

Comment: Perhaps I could use the restful path, but a) i'm not using restful paths in my app and b), like the @Yar said, I'd have to update that everywhere.